# Migrate GitLab CE 11 Omnibus to Docker

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

Which steps are necessary to migrate a GitLab CE 11 omnibus installation to Docker?

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post -
https://blog.jscrambler.com/migrating-your-gitlab-infrastructure-into-docker/

But the content seems pretty irrelevant and the commands are all messed up, like too much whitespace and the wrong methods in the dockerfile. Seems pretty dated when comparing the current release to the release this was written for. Could be a good start point though.